# Longitudinal IRT estimation - wrong approaches?

Tags: estimation, panel-data, item-response-theory

I have been fitting longitudinal IRT models, checking for measurement invariance over time, constraining item parameters not to change over time, as recommended in the literature, and had good experience with estimation using a Bayesian framework (using software called STAN) based on my simulation work.

Recently I came across IRT examples by pharmacometricians using NONMEM software. They are not able to estimate the item and person parameters jointly over time, instead they first estimate item parameters at baseline visit (time = 0), then in the second step the estimate longitudinal GRM by plugging in the item parameter estimates from the first stage and only estimate the person parameters.
I am almost sure this procedure underestimates the variability in the item parameters and will produce biased estimates of the person parameters at the end. Does anyone have a good reference for a "mathematical proof" of why this two stage approach and parameter fixing produces biased estimates?